# Is [0.1, 1[ countable? (Or, why can a decimal number have an infinite of digits, but a whole number cannot?)

Tags: infinity

Note: I'm not asking about `[0,1]`, I'm explicitly asking about `[0.1, 1]`.

I'm being told `[0.1, 1]` is not countable. It's clear for me that `[0,1]` isn't, but it feels less clear for `[0.1, 1]`, and I'll try to explain my understanding:

Essentially the idea is that if I can map every number in `[0.1, 1]` on a unique whole number it's countable, otherwise it's not. So the idea would be to just remove the `0.` and what remains is the unique whole number.

`0.123` maps to `123`, `0.123456789101112` maps to `123456789101112`, `0.1` maps to `1`. Since we're already mapping `0.1` to `1` we can't map `1` to it too, so we map `1` to `0`. For any example you can write down in it's decimal form, this would work for. However...

An obvious example where this might/does break down is for instance the number `pi/4`, which has an infinite number of decimals. So we can't map a whole number onto it. Or can we? I don't know.

So why is it allowed for a decimal number to have infinite digits, but a whole number cannot? Or is that just the definition of whole numbers and the "countability" of a set, like the difference between rational and irrational numbers?

Comment: Note that there's a bijection between $[0.1,1]$ and $[0, 1]$: send $x\in [0.1,1]$ to ${x-0.1\over 0.9}.$

Comment: A positive integer must have finite many digits because we must be able to reach it in a finite number of steps by adding $1$ over and over again beginning with $0$. In each step, the number of digits can increase only by $1$ (and this only if we arrive at a new power of $10$ , but this does not matter for the argument). Therefore, no positive integer can have infinite many digits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not countable. The quickest way to see this, if you already accept that $[0,1]$ is uncountable, is with a map $f(x) = \frac{x-0.1}{0.9}$, which is a bijection from $[0.1,1]$ to $[0,1]$.

> An obvious example where this might/does break down is for instance the number $\pi/4$, which has an infinite number of decimals. So we can't map a whole number onto it. Or can we? I don't know.

Correct. Or take a number like $\frac19 = 0.\bar1$: what should this map to?

> So why is it allowed for a decimal number to have infinite digits, but a whole number cannot? Or is that just the definition of whole numbers and the "countability" of a set, like the difference between rational and irrational numbers?

Informally, a number can have infinitely digits after the decimal point because each new digit makes it more and more precise: $3, 3.1, 3.14, 3.141, \ldots$ is getting closer and closer to some number (perhaps $\pi$). Adding digits to the left of the decimal point, on the other hand, makes the number explode: $1, 21, 321, 9321, \ldots$ isn't approaching any given number, it's shooting off to infinity.

Comment: Yes, any number with an infinite number of digits doesn't work. That's why I added the second part of the question, "why can't a whole number have an infinite number of digits?". Because 0.1¯ would just map to 1¯. But from the other answer as well, I can live with the explanation that a whole number can't have an infinite number of digits. That sounds fair to me.

Comment: Oh! Your update, explaining how a decimal gets more precise, but a whole number would explode, that really helps giving it a more "intuitive" feel. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @TheOddler On that note, remember how the real numbers are defined: they literally *are* (equivalence classes of) "[increasingly precise approximations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_sequence)."

Comment: Interesting, thanks! Also very kind of you to say "remember how..." as if I ever knew that.

Comment: @TheOddler A lot of math consists of remembering things one never knew. :P ("In retrospect that definition is *exactly* the thing that formalizes the intuition I had but never actually said out loud!")

Answer (score 0):

A simpler example than $\frac\pi4$ is $\frac13=0.3333333\ldots$

Anyway, our way of representing natural numbers is defined in such a way that any such number can be represented using only finitely many digits. And therefore that function that you mentioned is undefined for infinitely many elements of $[0.1,1]$.

Comment: Right, this was what I was thinking too then. Essentially it's just a definition. A whole number can't have an infinite number of digits.

Comment: @TheOddler Note that in some sense that's tautological: since "whole number" and "finite" are pretty much the same concept, this is similar to saying "Every whole number has a whole number of digits," which is much less interesting.

Comment: Fair, but anything with infinity gets weird, so I guess I'll forgive my younger self. Thanks a lot for the explanation!